# How to add quotes in a Postgres native query string in Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

There is a native query in a Java file for a Postgres database.

```
String REPORT = "where bpd.b.id = :bId and s.stock = true and (c.risk = true or c.risk2 = true) and crs.above_threshold = true and (s.cas = sac.cas_number or sac.cas_number is null) ";
```

I would like to add

```
c.risk = true or c.risk2 = 'Unknown'
```

however this doesn't return any more result

how do I add string values inside the native query ?

Comment: That should work, maybe you could show us the complete query string after your edit.

Comment: Oh wait, first `risk` is a boolean and then all of a sudden it is a string? Care to explain?